# Were masks imported to China in Jan-Feb resold to Mexico at 20-30 times the price in March?

Tags: china, covid-19, mexico, trade

Global News [reports](https://globalnews.ca/news/6858818/coronavirus-china-united-front-canada-protective-equipment-shortage/)

> In March, the masks sold to China in January and February were being sold back to Mexico at 20 to 30 times the price, according to [Jorge] Guajardo [Mexico’s former ambassador to Beijing].

There doesn't seem to be much doubt regarding China's [imports](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47236/did-china-import-2-billion-masks-earlier-this-year-to-control-covid-19) in that period at least according to China's own official customs' documents.

But were [some of] these stocks sold to Mexico and at 20-30 times the price thereafter? (And was this a significant quantity being resold at such high markup, to make the claim more than nominally correct? Note that the claim say "the masks", as if all of China's earlier imports were [being] resold to Mexico, but the claim is almost certainly false if read that way.)

Comment: Who is the monolithic "they" in question? Are all businesses owned by the Chinese government?  Are we talking about sales to the government, or to a government-owned corporation, or are we talking about one of the myriad of business entities like the ones who sell me charging cables and iPhone compatible parts on eBay? If it's the latter, I'm not sure it would be even notable that they'd turn around and jack up prices if their commodity was suddenly in red-hot demand and tight supply.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: answers could clarify that. Note that the quoted claim only says "masks sold to China [...] were being sold back". The wonders of passive voice. Also the quote says "*the* masks" as if it were all of those 2 billion, but I'm giving the source a pass on that, as the claim is almost certainly false if read that way.